# OpenGLES glEnableVertexAttribArray

Tags: opengles, glsl

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает. Как сильно glEnableVertexAttribArray() просаживает скорость программы?
У нас софт для визуализации, и очень важна скорость. Прям очень сильно важна. В текущей версии glEnableVertexAttribArray() вызывается один раз при инициализации, и в шейдерах используется всего один атрибут. Но теперь стоит задача, для решения которой одного атрибута не достаточно (в 4 вещественных канала данные никак не умещаются). Но добавление нового атрибута приводит к тому, что вместо одного единственного вызова glEnableVertexAttribArray() при инициализации, и одного вызова glVertexAttribPointer(...) при отрисовке, приходиться три раза вызывать glEnableVertexAttribArray(), три раза glVertexAttribPointer(...) и три glDisableVertexAttribArray() при каждой отрисовке!

```
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
```

vs

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(...);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(...);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

пихай все данные в один массив и тормозов не будет.(x,y,z,tx,ty,tz,nx,ny,nz и тд)